# Running flutter project on android device

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how to fix this error?:
[  +91 ms] Not watching D:\Code\flutter projects\icag_app\android since the file system is not supported

I tried reinstalling Android Studio but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: add some error screens or error texts first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.